# Concatenate String in Java Script Attribute in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how to put multivariable in button attributes?

Here's the example

```
btnLookupNo.Attributes.Add("onClick", "showLookUpWindow('',");return true")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to pass more than one `parameter` to javascript `function` by looking your attempt in Add method. You can use `+` to concatenate the variables in the javascript function call and you need to take care of quotes like this,

*In code behind*

```
string var1 = "string 1";
string var2 = "string 2";
btnLookupNo.Attributes.Add("onClick", 
  "showLookUpWindow('" + var1 + "','" + var2 +"'); return true");
```

*In javascript*

```
function showLookUpWindow(arg1, arg2)
{
     alert(arg1);
     alert(arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat similar code by changing attributes.